Does the speed of the roll become infinitely large near the end of this motion of the fire hose problem described below?
There is a problem about the rolling motion of a fire hose which is explained in the images below. Since the speed gets infinitely large at the end, there is a problem in the mathematical model used to solve the problem. Can you explain the conceptual difficulty that makes the model invalid at the end of the motion?



Under the assumption of conservation of energy (and no loss mechanisms), is there a mistake?

This makes me think of Euler's disk, another rotational system that in theory shoots off into a mathematical singularity in a finite amount of time. The mistake is the mismatch between theory and practice - when fire hose is traveling half the speed of light, you cannot continue to ignore factors like friction or material properties which might have been negligible at everyday speeds. Formulas aren't physical and don't need to give physical results - it is not a "mistake" that the gravitational force becomes infinite between two bodies separated by 0 distance, for example.

This problem is different from the gravitational force that becomes infinite when distance between two bodies is zero, because, that is something impossible in reality whereas unrolling of a fire hose until the end is perfectly possible in reality.

This is not a mistake but "singularity showing up" due to the mathematical model used to solve this problem.

There is no mistake. The problem makes implicit assumptions that are perfectly reasonable under most circumstances. But when things get extreme like at the end, the assumptions no longer hold up.
One assumption is that the fire hose doesn't stretch at all. It is strong enough that Usual forces don't stretch it enough to see. In the same way, solids are usually assumed to be perfectly rigid, but at the same time flexible enough for sound to propagate.
Another assumption is that as the hose unrolls, all the energy that was in the rolled up part stays in the rolled up part. This is reasonable. If you look at the very bottom of the roll, the part in contact with the ground is at rest. So it is slowed to a stop by internal forces. The equal and opposite reaction forces on the rest of the roll must speed the roll up. None is transmitted to the ground. So little is lost as heat that you can ignore it.
At the very end, there is no more roll. The forces that stop the end might come from the unrolled part of the hose. You might see the reaction force flip it around.
The tip might be going fast enough that energy might be converted to heat or even tearing of the hose. A whip is designed for this. It gets thinner near the tip, so the energy makes a smaller mass move. It moves faster and faster. The tip can break the speed of sound. Reasonable assumptions fall apart when that comes to a sudden stop.

Thank you for detailed explanation of the reasons which cause the failure of the mathematical model used to solve the problem.
